# function ambiguity in java

Tags: java, function, ambiguity

in java, i'm facing a function ambiguity. basically i'm overloading a variadic function
i'm defining function like

```
        static void f(Integer... a)
        {
            // .. some statements

        }

        static void f(float f,Integer... a)
        {
            // .. some other statements
        }
```

can calling the function with following function calls

```
f(1,2);
f(1.2f,1,2);
```

and this error message pops up

```
error: reference to f is ambiguous, both method f(Integer...) in Test and method f(float,Integer...) in Test match
        f(1,2);
        ^
```

can someone help me to understand if i'm missing any basic concept in java here. thnx ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

both method can take the first parameters you've entered `f(1,2);` and that's why you get ambiguity.
if you'll do

```
f((float)1,2);
```

you won't get the error for example

Comment: but if i cast first argument to float, f(float f,Integer... a) version will work always. i mean i don't seem to find a way to call f(Integer... a) version this way. any help ?

Comment: i'm not suggesting that, but you can wherite a function  f(char, Integer... a) and that way baypass the problem. there is no other way because an integer can always go as a float and that means you will always get ambiguity...

Comment: thnx for the pointer. used f(int b , Integer... a) to solve the ambiguity .. :)

Answer (score 3):

In Java language, int values can be automatically casted to float values (The opposite is not allowed).

Therefore, when you make a call to

```
f(1,2)
```

Java compiler matches all possible signatures that automatic type-conversions allow, i.e:

- f(int, int)
- f(float, int)
- f(float, float)
- f(int, float)
- f(int, ...)
- f(float, ...)

There resides the ambiguity for which the compiler does not know if you meant to call f(int, ...) or f(float, float).

Comment: can you suggest me any further reading regarding this topic ?

Comment: method signature matching for selecting method for invocation is explained in detail in the following JLS section: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2

Comment: You may also want to take a look at Method Invocation Conversion section at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3

Answer (score 2):

When several methods are applicable, the compiler tries to find the most specific one. If two methods are maximally specific, there is an ambiguity and you get an error.

In summary (the [actual rules](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2) are a little more complicated):

- the compiler determines that for `f(1, 2)`, both methods are applicable (1 can be an integer or a float)
- the compiler then needs to determine [which method is more specific](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5): in your case, none is more specific in the sense defined in the specifications because there is no relationship between `float` and `Integer` (examples: if you had a `f(int i, Integer... j)` vs. `f(float f, Integer... j)`, the former would be more specific because `int` is more specific than `float` among primitives. Similarly, if you had a `f(Number f, Integer... i)` vs. a  `f(Integer... i)`, the latter would be more specific because `Integer` extends `Number`).

Comment: Note that with `int...` there would be no ambiguity. The key ingredient here are the autoboxing rules.

Answer (score 1):

The runtime can choose to cast the function with the list of integers to call either function.  That's where the confusion lies.  Any list of integers you supply can also be turned into another call with the single leading float followed by a list of integers.